JIRA closed tickets how can I modify
Hi in JIRA agile board can someone please advise how I can amend a ticket marked as 'done'/'completed'. Users on our project cannot amended or move the ticket to another status like 'in progress'

You need to check you workflow for the JIRA and need to modify the flow for it. Incase, if  you don't have permission then you need to contact admin. Please refer: https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/manage-issue-workflows/
